# Is there a neat way of converting lists into maps with the keys set to the elements of original collection and values set to an enum in java

Tags: java, dictionary, enums, set, java-stream

Java newbie...
I have a dictionary like so:

```
electronictypeModelsMap =
{
"laptops" => ["macbook", "thinkpad", "yoga"],
"desktops" => ["macmini", "imac", "otherDesktop"],
"smartphones" => ["iphone", "galaxy5", "oneplus"]
}
```

There will only ever be a small number of keys like the 3 above but there will be a few hundred elements in each value (list)....

I want to be able to query it the other way around so :
`dictionary.get("macbook")` would return "laptops"

So I guess I want to convert into a new map with each element of each list as a key with the corresponding value set to the original key.
like this:

```
{
"macbook" => "laptops", 
"thinkpad" => "laptops", 
"yoga"=> "laptops", 
"macmini" => "desktops", 
"imac" => "desktops", 
"otherDesktop" => "desktops",
"iphone" => "smartphones", 
"galaxy5" =>  "smartphones", 
"oneplus" => "smartphones", 
}
```

Is there a neat way of doing this in Java 11?

In ruby you could do something like this

```
newMap = Hash.new 
electronictypeModelsMap.each do |k,v|
    v.each do |value| 
        newMap[value] = k 
    end 
end
```

Comment: flatmap it and collect it back to a map.

Comment: Is it guaranteed that there only be one key for each of the values in the list? If they are not unique, what do you want to have happen?

Comment: @DavidConrad The list can be taken to be a set. The elements will be unique.

Comment: It is not enough for the values to be unique within a list, they must be unique across all lists, or else "macbook" could map to both "laptops" and "phones".

Comment: Can you clarify what would you like to be an `enum`? Because an *enum* with a hundred of constants sounds a bit scary. Keep in mind that you need to **define** an *enum class* (it will not happen automatically), and then you can parse these strings. Also note that `MyEnum.valueOf()` can throw `IllegalArgumentException` in case if no enum-member with the matching name was found.

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko Sorry if I was unclear or phrased question incorrectly. I meant that the three categories: laptops, smartphones, desktops would be enums

Comment: Ok, and inside the initial map these three categories are stored as strings? And in the resulting map you want them to be enums, right?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a map like below:

```
Map<String,List<String>> electronictypeModelsMap = 
     Map.of("laptops",     List.of("macbook", "thinkpad", "yoga"),
            "desktops",    List.of("macmini", "imac", "otherDesktop"),
            "smartphones", List.of("iphone", "galaxy5", "oneplus"));
```

the simplest solution could be to use a nested `forEach`

```
Map<String,String> reMapped = new HashMap<>();

electronictypeModelsMap.forEach((key,list) -> {
    list.forEach(item -> {
        reMapped.put(item, key);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to produce another map. You can query the existing map, to find a key whose value contains the target string.

Streams are useful here to make that query.

Make some example data.

```java
Map < String, Set < String > > map =
        Map.of(
                "laptops" , Set.of( "macbook" , "thinkpad" , "yoga" ) ,
                "desktops" , Set.of( "macmini" , "imac" , "otherDesktop" ) ,
                "smartphones" , Set.of( "iphone" , "galaxy5" , "oneplus" )
        );
```

You said:

> dictionary.get("macbook") would return "laptops"

We can get all the entries of a map. Each entry is a key-value pairing, our string leading to a set of strings.

Make a stream of the entries of the map.

Filter the entries, looking for any whose value (the set of strings) contains our target, `macbook`. Stop looking after finding a match.

The result of this in an `Optional` entry. We need `Optional` here because there may be none found, we may have no hits.

In this case of your example, we know we have a hit, so proceed. We know the found entry’s value is a set containing our target. So extract the key, and report.

```
Optional < Map.Entry < String, Set < String > > > entry =
        map
                .entrySet()
                .stream()
                .filter( ( Map.Entry < String, Set < String > > stringSetEntry ) -> stringSetEntry.getValue().contains( "macbook" ) )
                .findAny();
String result = entry.get().getKey();
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/nTzR47).

> result = laptops

Answer (score 2):

If you're certain that every element in each list of values will be *unique* (i.e. distinct in the scope of all *map*) you can take the following approach:

- Create a stream over the entry set;
- Flatten the entries using `flatMap()` by creating a *new entry* based on each element of the list and a key to which the current list was mapped, so that a value becomes a key and vice versa.
- Collect the data into a map using `Collectors.toMap()`.

```
Map<String, List<String>> source = 
    Map.of("laptops", List.of("macbook", "thinkpad", "yoga"),
           "desktops", List.of("macmini", "imac", "otherDesktop"),
           "smartphones", List.of("iphone", "galaxy5", "oneplus"));

Map<String, String> result = 
    source.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(entry -> entry.getValue().stream().map(element -> 
                          Map.entry(element, entry.getKey())))
        .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

result.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "  =>  " + v));
```

*Output*

```
galaxy5  =>  smartphones
macmini  =>  desktops
macbook  =>  laptops
etc.
```

***Note*** that if in the initial map will have at least one element (like "macbook") that has been mapped to more than one category, the *collector* listed above will be unable to resolve duplicates, and it'll cause an `IllegalStateException`. As a remedy, you need to define how to override the value by providing a `mergeFunction` as the third argument of `toMap()`, or utilize the collector `Collectors.groupingBy()` instead to preserve all the values mapped to the same key.